# CAML - Get Items Under ALL existing Folders

Tags: list, caml-query, spservices, caml, scope

I have about 10 **Document folders** in my list 'ZooLibrary' and

I would like Query to display all the **PowerPoint files title** from the folders in the list, sorted by ID.

Currently, my View Scope='RecursiveAll' isn't working, any idea why?

```
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript> get() ;
function get() { var method = "GetListItems";                 
var webURL =  $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite() ;                     
var list = "ZooLibrarySlides";                      
var fieldsToRead = "<ViewFields>"+"<FieldRef Name='Name' />" +"</ViewFields>";
var query = "<Query><Where><Neq><FieldRef Name='ContentType' /><Value Type='Text'>Folder</Value></Neq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy></Query>";

$().SPServices 
({ operation: method, async: false, webURL: webURL, listName: list,
CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields Properties='True' />",
CAMLRowLimit: 8,
CAMLQueryOptions: "<QueryOptions><ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll' /></QueryOptions>",
CAMLQuery: query, completefunc: function (xData, Status)
{ $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() { 

if($(this).attr("ows_DocIcon")== "pptx")
{
var title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
$("#ISDataTable").append("<tr align='middle'>" +
"<td align='left' class='tooltip'>" +title+ ""</td>" + "</tr>");
}
}); } 
}); }; 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `CAMLQueryOption` to `GetListItems` call,

```
CAMLQueryOptions: "<QueryOptions><ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll'/></QueryOptions>"
```

Update your `CAMLQuey`,

```
CAMLQuery: "<Query> <Where> <Neq><FieldRef Name='ContentType' /><Value Type='Text'>Folder</Value></Neq> </Where> <OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy></Query>",
```

Use below logic inside the `completefunc` for each iteration,

```
$().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "ZooLibrarySlides",
        CAMLQuery: "<Query> <Where> <Neq><FieldRef Name='ContentType' /><Value Type='Text'>Folder</Value></Neq> </Where> <OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy></Query>",
        CAMLQueryOptions: "<QueryOptions><ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll'/></QueryOptions>",

        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {        
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() { 
                if($(this).attr("ows_DocIcon")== "pptx")
                {
                    alert("powerpoint");
                }
            });
        }
      });
```

Comment: However, the files displayed are folders and not the powerpoint slides within the folders?

Comment: @JacksonLim check the updated answer

Comment: Hi Vishnu, I have updated the above code. Really thanks for the help, unfortunately the folder search was stuck at the first level folders, I have folders within folders :( . The PowerPoint slides inside the folders wasn't showing up as well.

Comment: The code works for me. Try to remove `CAMLRowLimit` from your code. Also check the result xml using, `console.log(xData.responseText)` inside completefunc.

Comment: It's getting feedback! Just 1 question, i tried replacing the alert powerpoint with my append code. Why it doesn't work?

Comment: Check the no.of results `itemCount  = $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("rs:data").attr("ItemCount");
`. May be your PowerPoint files have different extension.(like ppt), then handle that one too.

Comment: For some reason, it's not picking up all the 10 folders and finding the latest files. It's only going deep into 1 folder.. Thanks Vishnu..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69898/discussion-between-vishnu-s-and-jackson-lim).